# retrieving xml data

Tags: php, xml

i want to retrieve data from xml file, i need to echo the attribute value of product

data.xml file----

```
<products>
<product  id="123"   />
</products>
```

php file---

```
$xml = new DomDocument();
$xmlFile = "data.xml";          
$xml= DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);          
$product = $xml->getElementsByTagName("product");    
foreach($product as $node)            
  {          
$id = $node->getElementsByAttributeName("id");         
$id = $address->item(0)->nodeValue;           
echo"$id";             
  }
```

Comment: Ah, you should quote your XML data: no way to tell what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of `getElementsByAttributeName()`, but if you want to just get the attribute of an element, the function is quite simple:

```
$xml = new DomDocument();
$xmlFile = "data.xml";          
$xml= DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);          
$product = $xml->getElementsByTagName("product");

foreach($product as $node) {          
  $id = $node->getAttribute("id");          
  echo $id;             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAttribute`:

```
$id = $node->getAttribute("id");
echo $id;
```

You may also want to refer to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) for other functions that you need ;)